# When using wget and logging the output of large file, how do I get rid of the progress bar?

Tags: bash, wget

I'm trying to look through my data and it takes a long time for me to finally get to the 100% when I scroll down. I've been looking through the manual and -b as well as -nv don't show me the end of the progress bar. I tried searching but it only gives me the first result, unless there's another command that can help me sort through all my data.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

From `man wget` :

```
-q
--quiet
       Turn off Wget's output.
```